# From form to javaScript map

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm trying to get the **form data** from my form **returned as** a simple **map** `Object {a: "b", c: "d"}`

I know I can `.serialize()` and `.serializeArray()` and then do it myself. Isn't there a jQuery function or something vailable for that?

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: No, there isn't. $.map and $.serializeArray both return arrays rather than objects (it's called an object, not a map). The only option is looping over the fields using either a for loop while loop or an each loop.

Comment: Have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/39248551#39248551

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight conversion form `formdata`to `JSON`. But here is a way to solve the problem:
http://blog.erdemagaoglu.com/post/1231059494/serialize-form-data-to-json-with-jquery